# Sending a message from unity webGL to Vue js

Tags: unity-game-engine, vue.js, communication, unity-webgl

this is more a general question! I created a vue js web page, where I wanted to add a unity webgl. It seems like it is very easy to call a unityfunction from javascript. But I could not find a suitable solution to send data from my unity webgl to vue js. 
In the manual they recommend to create something like a javascript library, but I don´t think that this makes sense in my context: [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)

Does anyone have a idea how to manage that or if that is even possible?
thanks in advance:)

Comment: The link your provided actually does make sense in any context, not knowing how to implement it, is another story, you can post your trials interacting with javascript, and any errors/walls you encountered, and we can probably help.

Comment: Sorry I think I was not specific enough. I can call functions from a .jslib file in unity. But I have a Vue js project here, an it would be nice if I was able to send data from my embedet unity application to Vue js. [Here](https://github.com/votetake/vue-unity-webgl) they claim that there is the possibility of a two way communication but they only explain one way. So I´m looking for the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're able to send data from vue to unity, sending data from unity to javascript is also easy.

1. Create an object to represent data we want to send to JS.

   ```
   public class Person
   {
       public string Name{get;set;}
       public string PhoneNumber{get;set;}
   }
   ```
2. Create your `UnityJavascipt.jslib` file and place it in a plugins
   folder.
3. We'll start with a simple javascript bridge function called `SendToJavscript`

   ```
   var UnityJavascipt =
   {
       // This object can hold variables for you.
       $JustAWebGLObject:
       {

       },

       SendToJavscript: function (dataJsonPtr)
       {
           // string paramters from unity get delivered to javascript as pointers.
           // So we get the actual string from the pointer.
           var dataJson = Pointer_stringify(dataJsonPtr);

           // Now convert the string to a javascript object.
           var jsobject = JSON.parse(dataJson);

           // Now you have the jsObject, Vue can access it from here.
           // You can use Vue API from here too.

           // I'll just debug some variables.
           console.log(jsobject.Name); // Kevin
           console.log(jsobject.PhoneNumber); //  011244455
       },

   };
   autoAddDeps(UnityJavascipt , '$JustAWebGLObject');
   mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, UnityJavascipt );
   ```
4. Create the extern PInvoke C# function, which by calling it, it calls the Javascipt bridge function, this extern function must match the Javascript `SendToJavscript` bridge function in name, parameters count, parameters types, parameters order.

   `public static extern void SendToJavscript(string jsonData);`
5. Now sending a person object to javascript.

   ```
   private void SendToJavscript_Test()
   {
      Person person = new Person();
      person.Name = "Kevin";
      person.PhoneNumber = "011244455";

      // We need to convert the object to javascript, cause we can't send objects 
      directly between C# and javascript.
      // Our bridge function handles converting the object back to a javascript 
      object.

      SendToJavscript(JsonUtility.ToJson(person));
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! But how can I access the jslib file from Vue when it is within the WebGL project?

Answer (score 0):

just place the whole folder of your code which includes your c# functions and also plugins under the folder vue-unity-webgl which you have installed as a package if you have followed the method by https://github.com/votetake/vue-unity-webgl